# Slapd service won't start, unable to open pid file

Tags: linux, ldap

I'm trying to set up a test LDAP-server for some developers but I'm running into some trouble.

```
service slapd start
```

errors so I run

```
/usr/sbin/slapd -d 1
```

and this gives me the following error at the end:

> unable to open pid file "/var/run/ldap/slapd.pid": 13 (Permission denied)
>
> slapd destroy: freeing system resources.
>
> slapd stopped.

The rights for /var/run/ldap are as follows:

```
root@pec:/var/run/ldap# ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 2 openldap openldap 60 2012-07-04 20:45
```

So I don't get why there is still a permission denied.
Syslog gives the following when running slapd:

```
Jul  4 21:00:27 pec slapd[13758]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.21 (Dec 19 2011 15:40:04) $#012#011buildd@allspice:/build/buildd/openldap-2.4.21/debian/build/servers/slapd
Jul  4 21:00:27 pec kernel: [8147247.203100] type=1503 audit(1341428427.953:64):  operation="truncate" pid=13758 parent=20433 profile="/usr/sbin/slapd" requested_mask="::w" denied_mask="::w" fsuid=0 ouid=119 name="/var/run/ldap/slapd.pid"
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What distribution are you running and how did you install OpenLDAP?

The error you got is from [AppArmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparmor) and tells you that it prevented `slapd` from creating it's `pid` file.

For Ubuntu: You should have something like the following in your `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.slapd` file:

```
  /{,var/}run/ldap/* w,
```

to allow this.

Normally, this should be set up to work without further configuration.

Comment: Running Ubuntu 10.04 server and installed it by copying everything from the master installation to another server and deleting some replicate statements from the config file. A rather brute way, maybe that's why this happened. I'll try your solution tonight. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, this method is most likely the source of your problem. One thing I noticed is that the default path for the slapd.pid on at least Ubuntu 12.04 is `/var/run/slapd.pid` and the AppArmor config file contains `/{,var/}run/slapd/* w,`, so if you overwrote the default, you will end up with problems.

Comment: One more hint: I highly recommend to convert the configuration to the modern `cn=config` format, which allows online reconfiguration of OpenLDAP.

Comment: I'm having some other problems now. When I start slapd using "/usr/sbin/slapd -d 1" The output blocks after "backend_startup_one: starting "dc=ulyssis,dc=org"
bdb_db_open: database "dc=ulyssis,dc=org": dbenv_open(/var/lib/ldap).
slapd starting"
Syslog output is only "
Jul  6 21:16:55 pec slapd[11415]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.21 (Dec 19 2011 15:40:04) $#012#011buildd@allspice:/build/buildd/openldap-2.4.21/debian/build/servers/slapd" which doesn't look like an error.. Any ideas?